# docker-dive extension for VsCode - error trying to run

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I installed the ["docker dive"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sandipchitale.docker-dive) extension in VsCode.  I aready had the Docker extension installed (which it requires). The docs say that Dive will run when an image is selected in the Docker extension images list. But that does not happen.

I entered "dive" in the command palette and "Docker:Dive" came up. I selected it and it displayed a list of my images for me to select one. When I did that, a new terminal window opened and tried to run `dive my_image_name`.

Then Powershell displayed the error: `dive : The term 'dive' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, ...`.
It's looking for "dive" in my PATH.

I'm confused. Docker Dive is an installed extension. Why should it also need it in my PATH? And if it really needs it, what is the path of the executable?

Comment: You need to install `dive` first. Just check the repo and you should be ready to go https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The docs aren't too clear. They say "The docker commands is expected to be available on the PATH." But they don't say the same about "dive" or that you need to install dive.exe.
The dive installation for Windows just downloads a .zip file that contains dive.exe. I copied this to C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin (instead putting it elsewhere and modifying my PATH). Then it worked.

Comment: What should be done when a comment answers a question? There no way to mark that as an answer.

Comment: I created an answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `dive` first. Just check the repo and you should be ready to go [github.com/wagoodman/dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive)

For `Windows` users. From the releases page https://github.com/wagoodman/dive/releases/
you need to find the `Assets` and download the `windows` one. Like https://github.com/wagoodman/dive/releases/download/v0.10.0/dive_0.10.0_windows_amd64.zip

You unzip the file and then you can create a folder on your C drive called `dive`, like `C:\dive`. Copy the executable `dive.exe` into`C:\dive`

Then you need to add that folder address into your `PATH`. For that you need to go to
[image]

From there you click on `Environment Variables`, then to `System variables`; from there you click on the `Path` variable and then on `Edit`. On the `Edit` window, add a new entry, with tyhe `New` button; the add `C:\dive` and click `Ok` button.
[image]

Then close and re open `Visual Studio Code`. Now the extension should work as intended.